# Changing an "." to an "_" in a C# string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm developing a piece of software in C# and the end result is an Excel spreadsheet. The title of the spreadsheet is created using several variables to explain exactly what the spreadsheet is. One of the variables is a string which contains data like this:

'1.1.1'

I need to convert it at the point of creating the spreadsheet to be:

'1_1_1'

I have tried using the `String.Replace` method but it just seems to ignore it. Any ideas?

Best Regards

Comment: Share some code.  Using String.Replace is the normal solution.

Comment: Please share the code that is failing.

Comment: Let's see the code you used, as Replace should do the trick easily.

Comment: "1.1.1".Replace('.', '_') doesnt work!!!!

Comment: More code would be nice, but I'm willing to bet that the 6 answers that all arrived within one minute of each other are onto something ;)

Comment: @DeveloperX That code does in fact do something. Assign the result to a value, and take a look.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I bet you doing this:

```
myString.Replace(".","_");
```

When you should be doing this:

```
myString = myString.Replace(".","_");
```

Remember, in .Net strings are immutable, so any changes result in a new string.

Comment: Congratulations on the fast Nice Answer badge `:)`

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I'm more then a little shocked at the response.

Answer (score 12):

Chances are you're ignoring the result of `string.Replace`. You need:

```
text = text.Replace('.', '_');
```

Just calling `Replace` doesn't change the *existing* string - it creates a *new* string and returns it. Strings are immutable in .NET - they never change after creation.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `string.Replace` are you remembering that you have to assign it?

```
yourString.Replace(".", "_");
```

Will do nothing.

```
string newString = yourString.Replace(".", "_");
```

will return the string with the dots replaced with underscores.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, you're not capturing the value returned by `String.Replace`. Strings are immutable, so `String.Replace` returns a new string, which you need to store a reference to.

```
string foo = "1.1.1";
foo = foo.Replace('.', '_');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "1.1.1";
input = input.Replace(".", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

strings are immutable, so make sure you're using it like this:

```
string myString = "1.1.1";
myString = myString.Replace('.', '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.Replace` is the right way to do this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        String myNumbers = "1.1.1";
        Console.WriteLine("after replace: " + myNumbers);
        myNumbers = myNumbers.Replace(".", "_");
        Console.WriteLine("after replace: " + myNumbers);
    }
```

will produce:

```
after replace: 1.1.1
after replace: 1_1_1
```